# in Ruby, how write a chainable method that chains a named scope N times if given N parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, method-chaining

I have a named scope `:name_not_like` that omits records from a relation if the :name matches a pattern

```
scope :name_not_like, lambda { |n| where('name NOT ILIKE ?', n) }
```

I have a method that omits every tom, dick, and harry:

```
def self.except_tom_dick_harry
  name_not_like("%tom%").name_not_like("%dick%").name_not_like("%harry%")
end
```

How can I write a method `except_these_names()` that given an array of N names will chain `name_not_like()` N times, so that

`except_these_names(["%tom%", "%dick%", "%harry%", "%sam%", "%fred%"])`
would do the same as except_tom_dick_harry() but for all the names in the array? Something like this:

```
def self.except_these_names(array_of_names)
  array_of_names.each do |name|
    # somehow 'stack' calls to name_not_like(name) ??
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work, I think. `reduce` fits well when you need to build-up on previous results.

```
def self.except_these_names(names)
  names.reduce(scoped) do |criteria, name|
    criteria.name_not_like("%#{name}%")
  end
end
```

Or actually, you can do with a simple each. Just put the `criteria` var outside of the loop.

```
def self.except_these_names(array_of_names)
  criteria = scoped
  array_of_names.each do |name|
    criteria = criteria.name_not_like(...)
  end

  criteria
end
```

Comment: Sweet. reduce() was exactly what was needed. Thank you!

Comment: However, I think it does not handle chaining correctly if there is an 'upstream' condition... If one calls Foo.some_other_method. except_these_names(names) then the initial condition of 'self' seems to override the some_other_method(). I'm thinking perhaps use 'scoped' (Rails 3)?

Comment: and except_these_names needs to be class method. With those two changes, the reduce() approach  works great in my specs. Thanks!